# Edit this tooltip implementation so the tooltip waits x seconds to hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, hide

i am creating this tooltip,

http://jsfiddle.net/GLZFc/

And it works fine for now! but I'd like the tooltip waited x seconds to hide (and if i mouseover again, the countdown to reset,

how could i implement this? (how can i combine setTimeout here?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/GLZFc/48/

Comment: There was one small problem that I just fixed. I updated my answer. `t` was undefined the first time you hovered, so i just added a check for that.

Comment: No dear, it's not working again! add the global call! LIKE this: http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/GLZFc/49/ and you'll get a +1 :) (P.S. yeah... you were missing the clear too! good edit!)

Comment: @roXon Without the `var` keyword, the variable becomes global once it's set in any function. Therefore, declaring it with `var t;` isn't necessary. (it doesn't exist on the first hover, which was why I added the `typeof` check

Comment: @Toni Michel Caubet I made a small edit that didn't make it into the final fiddle you posted. You should change `if(t)` to `if(typeof t != 'undefined')`

Answer (score 1):

You can call `.delay(someTime)` before your fadeout. (You need a newer version of JQuery in the fiddle)

http://jsfiddle.net/GLZFc/40/

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout("$('.miTooltip').fadeOut(500)", 5000);
```

Comment: Because its a bad idea to eval. which `setTimeout` is doing here.

Comment: "is a bad idea" is not a valid explanation @Daniel. please elaborate on why it is a bad idea.